# Control S3 Bucket Hosted Website's trailing slash redirects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, bucket

Automated the deployment of static sites to S3 with Ansible - not using any of Ansible's built in tools, necessarily, just using the CLI and local commands.

It's been working really well, but one issue I can't shake is when creating redirects, visiting the redirect with a trailing slash gives a 404, because S3 looks to serve /redirect/index.html rather than following the redirect.

Redirects are created through the API:

```
aws s3api put-object 
  --acl public-read 
  --website-redirect-location "https://devicelab.org/" 
  --key html/book
```

...where 'html' is the folder configured to serve the website from, 'book' is the desired redirect, and the homepage is the desired destination.

Visiting https://devicelab.org/book behaves as expected. Visiting https://devicelab.org/book/ (note trailing slash) shows 404 page.

I've tried creating an additional object `html/book/` (with trailing slash) but still get the 404.

How can I configure this behaviour / work around the issue?

Comment: just try creating a folder named books and try to put and sample helloworld HTML file in it ?

Comment: What if you `aws s3api put-object 
  --acl public-read 
  --website-redirect-location "https://devicelab.org/" 
  --key html/book/index.html`?  Also, you are showing `https` which suggests you may be using CloudFront.  If that's true, CloudFront may be serving cached responses from a previous request.  Verify this?  Cached responses have an `Age: [seconds]` response header.

Comment: Thanks for noticing Cloudfront; however I issue a cache invalidation with each deploy, so it's not that. 

As you suggested, I deployed the `html/book/index.html` redirect and the redirect /book/ now works with a trailing slash, which is great!

However, it means I need to create two objects for every redirect, which is a little grim. Is there some kind of routing rule I could set for the bucket that would redirect to `/book` (no trailing slash) if `/book/index.html` is absent?

Comment: P.S @Michael-sqlbot also, submit your comment above as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @Ben I think there's a potentially more elegant solution, if you are interested -- Lambda@Edge triggers can inspect the requests and issue redirects before the request is actually sent to the bucket, or potentially modify the bucket's response... and you could potentially use a new path pattern in CloudFront, `/*/` to associate only potentially relevant requests with the trigger.  What's the rule, here?  Certain paths redirect to the root, maybe, but it isn't clear from the example just what the general rule is, if there is one.